# Want Shortcut for Show My Caller ID

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcut

Im on iPhone 13 Pro and would like to have a shortcut to be able to easily turn off/on "Show My Caller ID", in the Phone Settings.  I do not see one.  Any ideas how I can create this?

I have created an open url shortcut using prefs:root=Phone and it will take me to the Phone settings screen - thats as far as I can get....